# AWS Amplify - update another user attributes

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

Is there a way I can update another user attributes using AWS amplify with cognito? I.e. when user reply to a post I want to change a rating of a person that started a thread. Or for this I will need a table in DB to manage it.

In docs i see that there is a method:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#adminUpdateUserAttributes-property

but I dont see a way to use it in Amplify.

Comment: Have you found any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen any API of `aws-amplify` which can alter user attributes as `admin`.

Generally, it is good practice not to duplicate data or keeping data duplication minimal if unavoidable. In other words, keeping a single source of truth. Use Cognito as only for authentication, I mean obtaining JWT token.

Rating, user basic info, and role; keep those at your own data source.

Comment: That is not always possible. In my case for example, we need to update the user attribute for phone_number_verified so the user receives an sms instead of an email for password reset. This should be done by admin, because if the user cannot log in then he cannot change the attribute himself. 

So The need for Admin Update User attributes in Amplify is not such a bad ideas